# Passing generic type using string (text) (Reflection ?)

Tags: java, generics

I store all my configurations in an xml file, and when I load them, I want each config rule to be stored in an Configuration object.

```
public class Configuration<T> {

    private String name;
    private T value;

    public Configuration(String configName, T value) {
        this.name = configName;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

In the XML I have a node that looks like it for each config: `<type>Integer</type>`.
This node holds the generic type that the Configuration's T will be, it will be used for the value.

When I load the `<type>` node, I get a string with value `"Integer"`. It can be anything, Object, MyClazz, but for example I wrote `"Integer"`.

**Is it possible to use a String value to initialize a class's generic type?**

*i.e in this case, Configuration object would be `Configuration<Integer>`*

Comment: `Is it possible to use a String value to initialize a class's generic type?` No, but why would you need to?

Comment: Because each configuration's value can be a different type, whether if its an integer, string, long etc

Comment: What's the end goal? How would you use it?

Comment: Would it be *better* to use instanceof checks instead? Since I know the amount of types I need.

Comment: Let's ignore the Configuration<T> class, and think this: You have a config xml file, or a text file where configRule = value, you want to load these configs to your application. Now, let's use HashMap<String, String>, but that means that all configs must be strings. what if i have few configs which are integers, few longs, and few are strings?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question doesn't make sense because of the type erasure.  Java Generics only exists at compile time.  During runtime all information about generic types is erased.  Since your object instantiation only happens during runtime, there is no room for generics to enter the picture at all.